# Save car id into html

Tags: html, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I working with Laravel, with blade views.

I have an array of cars. The user can choose one car from the list, each user can only show his list.

After selecting a car, a modal view appears into the same HTML for showing more information about the car.

If the user wants to remove the car, a post request is called, and **HERE** is the problem.

**How can I pass to the modal, the id of the car that he selected?** Because I need it for the post request if he wants to delete the car for example. May be save into variable.

I know how to pass parameter to the modal and then show it into "h3" or "inputs"but this id I can't show him, also he can't change it because he can modify it to remove another car from the list.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand what you need, so you have a main controller

```
public function cars()
{
$cars = Cars::all();
return view('cars',compact('cars'))
}
```

Then what you can do if you a view single car or delete you can pass the model.

```
public function single(Cars $cars)
{
return view('single',compact('cars'))
}
```

Your routes willl look like this

```
Route::get('cars',['uses' => 'CarsController@cars','as' => 'cars.all']);
Route::get('cars/{cars}',['uses' => 'CarsController@single' => 'as' => 'cars.single']);
```

and your HTML will be

```
<a href="{{route('cars.single',[$car->id])}}">{{$car->name}}</a>
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: The problem is that i have the view for the car in the same html because I have a modal. I don't need to go to another view to delete the car

Comment: So its all on 1 page? you could do an ajax call to all a controller??

Comment: If so you can use the answer I gave and just return a collection and use jquery to show HTML

Comment: Ok, you said:  href="{{route('cars.single',[$car->id])}}, but how can I know which Id he selected? because I'm on the same view, so I don't know wich Id he selected

Comment: I am going to add a new answer for using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If you was posting via Ajax you would do something like this.

```
@foreach($cars as $car)
<tr>
<td>{{$car->name}}</td>
<td><a class="view" href="#" data-id="{{$car->id}}">View</a></td>
</tr>
@endforeach

<script>
  $('.view').click(function() {
      var car = $(this);
      var car_id = car.data('id');

      $.ajax({
          url: '/car/single'+car_id,
          type: 'get',
          success: function(data) {
              $('#details').html(data);
          }
      });
  });
</script>
```

Will use the same controller:

```
public function single(Cars $cars)
{
  return $cars;
}
```